# Why are bullets still showing after list-style:none;

Tags: css

I don't want to display bullets for my videos listed on this page: `http://63.246.25.145/surety-bonds/contract-bonds/performance_bond.htm`

However, the bullets are still showing even after modifying the master.css file to ensure that my `list-style` is set to `none`.

```css
#page_bonds #videos {
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-top: 1px dotted #b3b3b3;
    list-style: none;  /*added for video show/hide*/
}
```

Comment: Also, read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: change that to #page_bonds #videos ul li and you'll be set

Comment: maybe the below is the solution(due to li:before clause):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151813/list-style-typenone-not-working-get-rid-of-the-bullets

Answer (score 3):

Good question; it's odd how the bullets show in IE even with the list-style:none;

This is the code that removed the bullets:

```
/* media query only applies style to IE10 and IE11 */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /* removes bullets in list items for IE11*/ 
    /* You may need the next line: #page_bonds #videos li */
    li {
        list-style-position: outside;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<li>` elements inherit from here:

```
ul {
    list-style: disc outside none;
}
```

You need to add

`#page_bonds #videos li {
  list-style: none;
}`

Comment: You don't need to add "important" attributes here. Just specify style for your li or ul element for #videos id.

Comment: It appears the following did it! '#page_bonds ul {
 list-style: none;
}'

Comment: Of course, if you style the parent, the style is propagated to childs. It's the same to add #page_bonds #videos ul { list-style: none; }

Answer (score 1):

The CSS which you posted refers to the `div` tags containing the `ul` of interest, but not the `ul` itself.  That makes it vulnerable to being overridden by CSS elsewhere which is styling all `ul` tags and giving them `list-style-type:disc`.

**What to do:**

You can either give the `ul` you want to affect its own `id` and target that or you can re-specify the CSS block you posted to refer to `#page_bonds #videos ul`.

**The general principle at work:**

The code you posted refers to specific elements with by specific `id`s, but without referring specifically to the element you want to change.  Since there is an explicit statement elsewhere in your CSS that gave all `ul` elements `list-style-type:disc`.  Now have at least two different instructions for the `ul` you care about.

CSS works on the principle of honoring the instructions which refer most specifically to the item of interest.  Perhaps somewhat unintuitively, in this case CSS picks the one that seems more general (`ul`) rather than the one that seems more specific (`#page_bonds #videos`).  But in reality `ul` is more specific based on the logic that instructions for a particular kind of element should trump the style of its containing `div`.

Remember: *Just because you refer to an* `id` *in the CSS, doesn't mean you're actually making the statement as specific as possible.*

Comment: I added the following to line 2795, but no luck [code] #page_bonds #videos ul {  /*added for video show/hide*/
  list-style: none !important;
 }[/code]

Comment: Rather than specifying list-style, try `list-style-type:none`.  Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

With cascading style sheets, the inheritance order for elements is not just a simple matter of include order - See the detailed explanation at - [Cascading order and Inheritance](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css).

In your case your list is inheriting value from `master.css` line 639:

```
ul {
    list-style: disc outside none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

either remove this reference or use `!important` or add a more specialised css tag.

Comment: I added !important to the more specialized css tag on line 2795 of my css file, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

CSS elements carry their values to the child element. To override this, use !important.

Try:

```
list-style: none !important;
```

Learn about !important [here.](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In the source for your page I can see that your list style is being overridden by this style sheet (63.246.25.145/styles/master.1361894679.css)

You can overcome this by changing your style to more accurately specify the list in question via

```
#videos ul li { list-style: none !important; }
```

Or you can edit the CSS linked into the page and change the cascade rules to allow the videos to have no list style.

[1]: