# list-style-type:none not working! Get rid of the bullets?

Tags: css, wordpress, list, html-lists

Could somebody help me and tell me what is creating bullets throughout my site?

bit.ly/12QJQ0F

(look at the form) and on the Social Media page its there too. Id just like to disable all of them altogether - I have list-style-type none in dozens of places in my css and theyre still popping up

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's coming from this line:

```
.contentarea ul li:before {
    color: #666666;
    content: "●";
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

:) Just edit that will fix it

Answer (score 3):

Here is your problem:

```
.contentarea ul li:before {
content: '●';
padding-right: 0px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
line-height: 20px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #666666;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At line `11030` of your `theme.css` file, you have the following:

```
.contentarea ul li:before {

     content: '\25cf';

}
```

That whole code block is your culprit.

An easy way to find things like this in Chrome is by right-clicking any item on the page and choosing "Inspect Element"... You can then view all styles being applied to the element, and from where.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS fix should be:

```
.contentarea ul li:before {
    content: "●";
}
```

If everything else fails try adding this just at the start of each line where you want to have a bullet:

```
&bull;
```

This is a workaround through an HTML entity, not CSS. However, using it has been a workaround for me in the past.