# LI list style not applying

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is my code, i am using this in wordpress site. "list-style: none" is not working, it displays 1,2.. for every li tag.

```
 <ul class="bxslider" style="width: auto; position: relative; -webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -471px, 0);">
     <li style="float: none; list-style: none; width: 683px; margin-bottom: 3px;" class="bx-clone">
          <blockquote>We are getting calls every now and then. You have done a great job. Our business is growing. I want to place an order for a new web site with you.<br /><br />
         <p style="text-align:right;margin-right:20px;">- Andrewan</p>
    </blockquote>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: can you paste the rest of html/css???

Comment: can you paste the css for bxslider???

Comment: add list-style:none to ul

Comment: Check my answer, I used list-style-type: none;

Comment: I fiddled your code, and i see no numbering lits. http://jsfiddle.net/RHG8K/  See for yourself. It must be something else.

Comment: check updated answer, use !important

Comment: this code works in fiddle..but when i use the same code in wordpress..it does not work

Comment: Can you show us the live website link? Maybe something overriding it.

Comment: Check this link - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151813/list-style-typenone-not-working-get-rid-of-the-bullets

Answer (score 0):

try putting `list-style:none` in the enclosing `ul` tag of the `li` tags.

**EDIT try adding `!important` after `list-style:none;`**
You may have a parent css rule with `!important` overriding the rule you want.

Comment: i don't think it would work....`list-style:none`, be it in `li` or `ul` serves the same purpose!

Comment: I need sleep is what I need.

Comment: You can delete this answer before going to bed. Good nite 'sleepy'

Comment: @AnkurDhanuka : i think he went to sleep....can you give the link to your live url, that might show something!!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an unordered list, there is no chance for getting 1,2,3 at every li. May be some tag is not closed properly.Now if you don't want to change your mark-up,the following code may help you.

```
.bxslider{
list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing try this in li { list-style-type: none !important; } 
i thing it's wrk fine.

Comment: try jquery css() function. It may resolved your issues.